# How to use TagBuilder in a Class Library project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use `TagBuilder` in a Class Library project. I have added references to `System.Web` and `System.Web.Mvc`(v3), but in my class file the `TagBuilder` class is not visible.

How can I use `TagBuilder` in a Class Library project?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Asp.Net MVC 3, it is located in:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll
```

In Asp.Net MVC 4, it is located in:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll
```

So make sure you have a reference to that dll.

Comment: and for MVC 5 you need: [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/)

Answer (score 11):

You also need a reference to System.Web.WebPages

Answer (score 0):

If you added the DLL (in System.Web.Mvc.dll), and the namespace, it should be visible to you as a class. Have you added the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `using` statement at the top of your file that references the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.  Since you have the reference added you should be good to go.  Have a look at the article '[Using the TagBuilder Class to Create HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs)' for more information and an example.

Answer (score 0):

Those answers are all correct for older versions of Asp.Net MVC, but these days it's probably best and easiest to just use NuGet Package Manager / "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.." and install the latest version of Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc in your project.